# Attach and or mount unmanaged page blob snapshot to another Azure VM using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

We are using unmanaged disks and want to be able to locate a blob given a Live VM name and a disk name, create a snapshot of the disk and mount that disk in another (backup) VM and gain access to its file system.

Live VM may be Linux or Windows
Backup VM will typically be Linux but possibly Windows

So far, I am able to locate the live VM, and the page blob I want to snapshot and create the snapshot.

```
$key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccount -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName | select -first 1).Value
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount  -StorageAccountKey $key
$blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $context -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName
$snapshot = $blob.ICloudBlob.CreateSnapshot()
```

I now want to mount the snapshot identified by $snapshot on the backup VM. Is this possible?

I don't mind if it requires additional steps (such as copying the snapshot to another blob) but would rather keep the steps to a minimum.

Comment: Best to ask this question on ServerFault, not here. But... you cannot mount a snapshot. You'll need to copy the snapshot to its own page blob first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did wonder if that might be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. Copying the snapshot to a blob, and then attaching the blob is the way to do it.